# Frame Set not supported

Tags: c++, qt, qml, intel

I am creating an app using Qt5.15(Qml), Visual studio 2019, C++ and the "im-show" example from the Intel RealSense SDK.

I created a special « Rectangle » where i am displaying the stream of my RealSense on my app interface after clicking on the start button that I have created also. To link my User interface with my C++ codes, i created a C++ file named « Backend.h & Backend.cpp » where I create my functions so I can use them on my QML code directly.

I was able to get the application work, i.e. the interface is displayed with all the Qt components without any problems, but when I click on the "start button" to start streaming the intel scanner, I get an error saying "Frame set not supported yet"...

Can someone help me or explain how can I figure this out ?

Thanks in advance.

ps : I am using the intel Realsense D455, a scanner with an RGB camera and a depth camera.

Comment: please provide [mcve] instead of explaining your code

Comment: HI, i am trying the reproduce this project https://github.com/Jiloc/tighty

Comment: Porblem solved ! thank y'all